# How to get SIP to find .sip files for and installed library

Tags: pyqt

I'm trying to create python bindings for [source-highlight-qt](http://srchiliteqt.sourceforge.net/) using sip.

I'm working on ubuntu - I've installed python-qt4-dev, which has installed the pyqt sip files to /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/

In my sip file, I've got this import:

```
%Import QtCore/qstring.sip
```

I'm getting this error when I run my configure.py:

```
sip: Unable to find file "QtCore/qstring.sip"
```

How do I get sip to find the pyqt .sip files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

In my configure.py, I needed to create a pyqtconfig:

```
from PyQt4 import pyqtconfig
config = pyqtconfig.Configuration()
```

and then add directories for sip to include:

```
command = " ".join(
    [config.sip_bin, "-c", ".", "-b", build_file,
     "-I"+config.pyqt_sip_dir,
     "-I"+config.qt_inc_dir, config.pyqt_sip_flags,
     "lib/GNUSyntaxHighlighter.sip"]
    )
```